# CSS to style textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

This is probably an easy fix but I can't figure it out. I am trying to style the textbox to be the same width as the listbox.

Comment: You have defined PairTextbox instead of PairTextBox, check: http://jsfiddle.net/up1f1wjx/

Comment: Just a little tip - in HTML there is a difference between a textbox and a text input. The element in your example is a text input rather than a textbox :)

Comment: you could make a div around the inputs and set the width to 100%
http://jsfiddle.net/nxmc83re/

Comment: Thanks for all the help I edited with another CSS question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to write ID properly,

**CSS**

```
.teststyles input#PairTextbox {
    width: 80%;           ^---Typo here. IDs are case-sensitive. 
}
```

Look updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4frmq840/26/)

Comment: Thanks I missed that, helpful

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo it's

```
.teststyles input#PairTextbox {
    width: 80%
}
```

because `PairTextbox` !== `PairTextBox`

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wilfredo1285/4frmq840/30/)

Answer (score 1):

you get your id name wrong in your css part.And instead of  `input` ,you should add `input[type='text']` as  selector,otherwise it will effect all the input elements under the same class name.it will be

```
     .teststyles input[type='text'] #PairTextbox {
    width:80%;
}
```

Or  you can add size attribute to your input text field.That will do .

```
<input id="PairTextbox" type="text" size='38'/>
```

for edit section:

just cut and paste the desired element and place it at the top of listItem box in your html.you should probably be able to do it by yourself .[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4frmq840/37/)

Comment: Thank you. Can you also help with the EDIT i made to the original question? @Wilfredo-P